# Clear only one of multiple floated items

Tags: css, css-float

I have a layout where there are two items floated right and another item floated left. In between I want to have a `div` that clears only one the second of the right floated item.

E.g. I have a layout with a div floated to the right of the page, then a floated image on the left, and another floated image on the right. I want to clear only the image that is floated on the right but not the whole `div`.

Is there a way to clear only one of the floated items on the right. See http://www.davidapfel.com/testimonials.html, I want to put the image higher up and then put a div underneath the floated image but next to the bar on the right.

Is there any way to do this, or any other easy way of accomplishing this, perhaps without using float?

Thanks very much

Comment: Have you tried grouping the image and `div` inside a `div`? You then float the container `div`. something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Uekeb/1/

Comment: Good designs are usually simple, try to simplify those you can't build in 1 hour, because it will cost more time to later maintain.

Comment: @Biotox But I don't want to float the div - only the image, so how would a container div help?

Comment: @Rufus is it possible to achieve something similar in a simpler way?

Comment: Which image are you trying to float/clear? The one under `Residential Homes & Sheltered Housing` or above it?

Comment: I want to move the image under "Residential Homes & Sheletered Housing" higher up on the page, and float it right as it is now, then I want the <h2> to clear that image without clearing the rest of the bar that goes down the right hand side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyttp/1)

**HTML**

```
<img height=200 src='/img/top-bg.png' />
<div id='container'>
    <img height=100 src='/img/top-bg.png' /><br />
    my text
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#container {
    float:left;
}
#container br{
    clear:left;
}
```

It doesn't involve nested `div`s, just one to keep the `br` from clearing the second image.

Comment: It's a long time since I posted this question but I think this answers it.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image that's floated to the right in a div, and float the div right not the image, then you can add clear:right; to your div class and padded as needed.

You can also float your h2 tag, or make it display:inline-block and that will let you move your right side image up a little more right now the h2 is going across the page pushing everything down.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what I meant. I want to float the image to the right. If wrap the image in a `div` and set `clear:right` to the div, the image will move down to clear the bar at the right hand side which is NOT what I was looking for. I want to leave the image where it is and make the `h2` tag clear the floated image, but hover alongside the bits to the right (i.e. not to clear them). I hope that explains it. Thanks very much

Comment: Hi, your original post said you wanted to put the image higher up? I'm not clear on what you need to do. But if you use Chrome check out it's Developers tools by clicking the wrench in the top right -> Tools -> Developer tools. Or right mouse click your image and click Inspect Element which will open developer tools. Once open you can also click the magnifying glass in the bottom left corner of the Dev tools window. Then click an element on your page. You can play around with the CSS and see the changes in real time. Also try playing with z-index to float divs on top of each other